# Use PowerShell to bulk process pairs of numeric files

Tags: powershell

I've got a folder with pairs of files in them, named as follows:

T1_00001.jpg and T2_00001.jpg, T1_00002.jpg and T2_00002.jpg, etc...

I need to run a 3rd party tool to process these files in pairs - it takes the two matching T1 and T2 filenames and requires an output filename (can just be the relevant trailing number to identify it):

"convert -input1 T1_00001.jpg -input2 T2_00001.jpg -output 00001.jpg"

I'd like to repeat this command for all pairs of files in a specific folder. All filenames start with T1/T2 and are sequentially numbered from 00001 onwards.

I've tried a long winded way of doing this using loops and by counting all the files, but I'm sure there will be a simple way of doing this - I'm not just aware of how to make the most of PowerShell. Any advice would be most welcome.

**edit**: I've changed this to the following code, which has avoided loops - however the code is simply displayed and not executed:

```
$convertFile = "C:\Temp\convert.exe"
$path = "C:\Temp\Images";
Set-Location -Path $path;
$fileNumber = Get-ChildItem -filter 'T1_*' -path $path | Measure-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Count;

1..$fileNumber | % { 'invoke-expression -command "convert T1_{0:00000}.jpg T2_{0:00000}.jpg -compose minus -composite Subtracted_{0:00000}.jpg"' -f $_ }
```

Comment: So what have you got so far? Please show your code. We will not write ready to use code on request.

Comment: I've updated the code block with my results so far.

Comment: Just a little tweak: you can get the count of your files a little easier with this: `(Get-ChildItem -filter 'T1_*' -path $path).count`. ;-) But actually you don't need that at all. If you run `Get-ChildItem` you can iterate with a `Foreach-Object` loop over all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Group-Object` to group the files on the second part of the filename (after `_`), then loop through each group to run the command

```
#Create samplefiles for demo
0..5 | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Name ("T1_{0:00000}.jpg" -f $_) > $null
    New-Item -ItemType File -Name ("T2_{0:00000}.jpg" -f $_) > $null
}

#Find Tx_something.jpg-files
Get-ChildItem -Filter "T?_*.jpg" |
#Group on ID after _ in filename
Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Split("_")[1] } |
ForEach-Object { 
    #Find file in group starting with T1
    $input1 = $_.Group -match '^T1'
    $input2 = $_.Group -match '^T2'
    $output = "$($_.Name).jpg"

    convert -input1 "$($input1.Name)" -input2 "$($input2.Name)" -output $output
}
```

Output (added `Write-Host` to simulate the commands that would be executed):

```
convert -input1 T1_00000.jpg -input2 T2_00000.jpg -output 00000.jpg
convert -input1 T1_00001.jpg -input2 T2_00001.jpg -output 00001.jpg
convert -input1 T1_00002.jpg -input2 T2_00002.jpg -output 00002.jpg
convert -input1 T1_00003.jpg -input2 T2_00003.jpg -output 00003.jpg
convert -input1 T1_00004.jpg -input2 T2_00004.jpg -output 00004.jpg
convert -input1 T1_00005.jpg -input2 T2_00005.jpg -output 00005.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you, this grouping is much better than the way I had tried. I will modify my code to use this method.